# Solving a differential equation with mixed conditions using DSolve

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations

I want to solve a differential equation 
$$ \frac{d}{dx}\left(k_0 \left(\frac{T(x)}{T_0}\right)^n \frac{dT(x)}{dx}\right)=0,$$ 
with boundary conditions: $T(l)=T_0$, $\;T'(0)=-\frac{q_0}{k_0 T(0)^n}\;$
using `DSolve`, but I cannot get a solution. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Your equation appears to be missing a bracket, `(`. Also, did you mean to write $T[x]$ instead of $T[l]$ in the boundary conditions?

Comment: T is a function of x

Comment: d/dx[k0 (T/T0)^n dT/dx]=0 
Boundary Condition is:
at x=L, T=T0,
at x=0, dT/dx= -q0/(k0 T(0))

Comment: Funny that k0 does not play any role in the equation. You can cancel it out.

Comment: It showed in boundary conditions

Comment: It shows up now! :-). At any rate, why don't you solve with a ballistic method? Specify condition at the same extreme of the x interval, leaving the unknown one as a parameter `a`. For example `sol = DSolve[Flatten[{eq, T[0] == a, T'[0] == -q0/(ko To^n)}], T[x], x]` then you'll set the corresponding function of parameter `a` (e.g. use `f[x_, a_] = T[x] /. Last[sol]`) equal to your condition at the other extreme. In this way you can solve for `a` in closed form for specific values of `n`. Then you plug `a` into your solution and massage it a bit.

Comment: Ops, the second condition above should use `a` instead of `To`.

Answer (score 6):

I would just notice that

$$ \frac{d}{dx}(k_0 (\frac{T[x]}{T_0})^n \frac{dT[x]}{dx})=k_0/T_0^n \frac{1}{n+1}\frac{d}{d x^2} T[x]^{n+1}$$

and therefore I'd solve it as below :

```
(* Solve the differential equation and rename the integration constants *)
aux = (Tnp1 /. First@DSolve[k0/T0^n 1/(n+1) Derivative[2][Tnp1][x] == 0, Tnp1, x]) 
  /. {C[1] -> a, C[2] -> b}

(* The solution with the constants to be fixed *)
solT = Function[x, (aux[x])^(1/(n + 1)) ]

(* Solve for the constants *)
const = FullSimplify[Solve[{solT[l] == T0, solT'[0] solT[0]^n == -q0/k0} , {a, b}], 
    Assumptions -> {n > 0}]
(* {{a -> (l (1 + n) q0)/k0 + T0^(1 + n), b -> -(((1 + n) q0)/k0)}} *)

(* put everything together *)
finalT[x_] = solT[x] /. First[const]
(* ((l (1 + n) q0)/k0 + T0^(1 + n) - ((1 + n) q0 x)/k0)^(1/(1 + n)) *)
```

Check :

```
Block[{n = 6},
      {finalT[l], finalT'[0] finalT[0]^n}
]
(* {(T0^7)^(1/7), -(q0/k0)} *)
```

Comment: @Nasser I'm just saying $\frac{d}{dx}T^{n+1} = (n+1)\ T^n\  \frac{d}{dx} T$.

Comment: @Artes I don't do terrible calculus on purpose. Please help us correcting our mistakes.

Comment: Here it is again: $\frac{d}{dx}\left(  T^{n}\frac{dT}{dx}\right)  =\frac{dT^{n}}{dx}\frac
{dT}{dx}+T^{n}\frac{d^{2}T}{dx^{2}}=nT^{n-1}\frac{dT}{dx}\frac{dT}{dx}
+T^{n}\frac{d^{2}T}{dx^{2}}=nT^{n-1}\left(  \frac{dT}{dx}\right)  ^{2}
+T^{n}\frac{d^{2}T}{dx^{2}}$

Comment: @Nasser What you do is correct but the simplification happens if you work backwards; you don't want to expand the derivative but rather use that $T^n \frac{d}{dx T} = \frac{1}{n+1} \frac{d}{d x}T^{n+1}$. This way the equation is simply $\frac{d}{dx^2} T^{n+1} = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your BC's are not linear. So Mathematica can't solve for `C[1]` and `C[2]`. May be if you use numerical values for some of the parameters, then they can be solved.

You can solve leaving the IC's out and get a solution with `C[1]` and `C[2]` later as follows

```
ClearAll[x, n, k0, T, q, len]
f[x_, n_] := k0  (T[x]/T0)^n T'[x]
T[x_] = T[x] /. Last@DSolve[D[f[x, n], x] == 0, T[x], x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[T[x] /. {len -> 1, C[1] -> 2, C[2] -> 3, n -> 3}, {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
bc1 = T[len] == T0
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
c2 = C[2] /. First@Solve[bc1, C[2]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
bc2 = (T'[x] /. x -> 0) == - q0/(k0 (T /. x -> 0)^n)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
eqForC1 = bc2 /. C[2] -> c2
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And now just need to solve for `C[1]` and then can find `C[2]` and hence the solution. But to solve for C[1], need numerical solution as it is non-linear. Hence need numerical values for the parameters in the equation for `C[1]`.

Comment: The problem is that the solution from last `DSolve` is not like the what I had now. The result should be in the form T[x]=(c1*x+c2)^(n+1).

Answer (score 1):

To complete my first comment (Hey, I've been scolded by the system because it was too long)
I suggest to use a shooting (or balistic) method: instead of using mixed boundary conditions (at `x=0` and `x=l`), specify the values of `T` and `T'` at the same extreme of the `x` interval, leaving the one that did not appear in the original problem as a parameter a to be determined.
(I am not sure if `To` and `T[0]` should be the same, so you might want to adapt the code accordingly)

```
eq = Expand[D[ko (T[x]/To)^n  T'[x], x]] == 0

sol = DSolve[Flatten[{eq, T[0] == a, T'[0] == -q0/(ko a^n)}], T[x], x];
f[x_, a_] = T[x] /. Last[sol]
```

This will give you a hint of the value of a for generic integer `n` (I am using `First` here to return only one root per equation; perhaps a function capable of returning a real solution would be better):

```
Table[{k, a /. First[Solve[f[l, a] - To == 0/. n -> k, a]]}, {k, 0, 6}]
```

If you are confident you have found a closed form solution, you could try it into your `f[x,a]`, that is `T[x]` with initial condition `T[0]==a`. For example, (EDIT, earlier I had used `n` instead of `n+1`)

```
t[x_] = f[x, a] /. a -> (To^(n+1) + (n+1) l q0/ko)^(1/(n+1)) // PowerExpand // Simplify
```

I have implicitly assumed that `n` is an integer and the constants are all real. It is usually at this point that I discover I have used an equation different from the one of the actual problem. :-)
Still I hope this "extended comment" will point you in the right direction.

**newer EDIT**: this solution is remarkably similar to that found by b.gatessucks. As a matter of fact, if we bring the premultiplying constant inside the big bracket, we get the same solution. We can verify that it satisfies the differential equation

```
D[ko (t[x]/To)^n  t'[x], x]==0 // FullSimplify
    (* True *)
```

and the condition at `L`

```
t[l] == To // Simplify // PowerExpand
    (* True *)
```

And it also checks the condition on the derivative

```
t'[0] t[0]^n // Simplify // PowerExpand
    (* -q0/ko *)
```

(In my previous edits I was using To instead of T[0] as I should have done). Double check by specifying a value for n:

```
Table[t'[0] + q0/(ko t[0]^n) , {n, 0, 7}] // Simplify // PowerExpand
    (* {0,0,0,0,0,0,0} *)
```

Well, it appears that the shooting method works well, after all. It only needs someone less clumsy to manage it.

**older EDIT**: I wrote the part about using the wrong equation in mocking but it might very well be true. I am a bit confused by the role of To, since I tend to assume it is the value at `0`. Results can be more complicated without the simplification given by putting an`a` in the condition for `T'`.

Comment: you have a mistake here, the boundary condition is T[l]==a instead of T[0]==a

Comment: The idea of the shooting method is to use a parametric initial condition `a`, to be determined by compliance with the boundary condition it is replacing. Your boundary condition at l is imposed by f[l,a]==To. But I might have messed up To with T[0].